# What's with this weird error in the .Net CosmosDb SDK?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to run a very simple query against my Azure CosmosDb instance. Here is the query:

```
        var query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<string>(new QueryDefinition("SELECT c.id FROM c"));
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var feed = query.ReadNextAsync().Result;
            var ids = feed.Select(x => x);
            foreach(var id in ids)
            {
                idsInDatabase.Add(id);
            }
        }
        return idsInDatabase.ToArray();
```

But when it executes, I get an error stating that there is an "Unexpected character" in line 1, position 2, as seen below:

[image]

It's like it is trying to parse JSON instead of my SQL query. This example seems to follow the examples I've seen online. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of that query is a JSON that contains an "id" property, not a string, you are not using VALUE.

Have you tried with a Type like:

```
public class MyResult
{
   public string id { get; set; }
}

var query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyResult>(new QueryDefinition("SELECT c.id FROM c"));
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var feed = query.ReadNextAsync().Result;
            foreach(MyResult result in feed)
            {
                idsInDatabase.Add(result.id);
            }
        }
        return idsInDatabase.ToArray();
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. I needed to define an object with an attribute "id". I come from the SQL + Dapper world, where selecting a single column gets serialized to a string array, and something like this is valid.